# How to smooth sharp edge

Tags: modeling, smooth

I use bridge loop edges and grid fill to give a model inner face. but because the number of vert is small, there are many sharp edge.

In addition, SUBSURF modifier doesn't seem to have much effect. I wonder if there any way to smooth it?

you can get my blend file from [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try the Smooth Modifier.

Comment: @Leander I try Smooth Modifier, It can adjust the external shape, but the sharp edges caused by the mesh inside are still very obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing recalculte the normals in *Edit* mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>). Also <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Shade Auto Smooth*.

You have a lot of flat edges, they tend to sharpen the shading, see for example here:

[image]

If you want to make the shape rounder and the shading smoother you can select this edge, enable the *LoopTools* addon and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *LoopTools > Relax*, in the *Operator Box* choose *Cubic/Parallel/25*:

[image]

Also you could simplify the topology with some *Mesh > Checker Deselect* and dissolve the edges, bevel the edges, add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to round the shape...

[image]